# Jquery animate attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, autosize, autogrow

I use something like this, for auto growing (auto size) textarea:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    $(this).attr('rows', $(this).val().split("\n").length);
});
```

How to add smooth animation to auto growing for code above?

Function `.animate()` with `rows` doesn't work.

Comment: No need to use jQuery or javascript here - just use CSS3 transitions (set on the height)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use `height` CSS. Your code only works if the textarea is set to not wrap text.

Try something like this:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight+8)+"px";
});
```

Then, if you have suitable `transition` properties set on the textarea, it will animate.

Comment: Guys, Your code is growing when put some keyup, not new line and what for is 8px (why 8) in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try that, too: http://jsfiddle.net/bhzte/1/

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var rows = that.val().split("\n").length;
    that.attr('rows', rows);
    var lh = parseInt(that.css('line-height');)
        that.animate({height:lh*rows})
});
```

You can set the line-height in css file, style attr like `<textarea style="18px"></textarea>`
or with jquery:

```
$('textarea').css({'line-height':'18px'}).keyup(...});
```

**UPDATE**

You can do something like that to avoid shrinking:
http://jsfiddle.net/bhzte/4/

Comment: OK, pardon me you have to set line-height with pixel values for the textarea. Check out the update

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code==13) {
    $(this).attr('rows', $(this).val().split("\n").length + 1);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A8nxA/